# Get list of required BPLs for a given DLL, EXE or BPL

Tags: delphi, package, bpl, runtime-packages

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an *elegant* way of determining what BPLs are required by a given (*compiled*) DLL, EXE or BPL.

I'm not sure if this is even possible shy of simply scanning the binary for text references to *.bpl* filenames (*which would be prone to possible false-positives*).

Ideally I'd like to return a `TStringList` or even a comma-separated `String` containing the names of all required *.bpl* files.

Comment: http://www.peganza.com/#PAL does this kind of thing on source, but I don't think it reads .exe, etc. You might check though.

Comment: Not even the IDE does a reliable job of this or we wouldn't get "Unable to load X.BPL" when Y.BPL has already implicitly background-loaded that BPL without the IDE having any clue of that thing loading.  I really would like to know this too.

Comment: "DUMPBIN /imports" can do it perfectly reliably, so it is certainly possible.  However piping the output back into your program does not meet your criterion of elegance.

Comment: You can try reading the `Import address Table`of the PE file, but it only will show the load-time dependencies; AFAIK it is not possible to know every run-time dependency without disassembling or executing the application, if the application is running you can use the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` function with the  TH32CS_SNAPMODULE flag.

Comment: You could recursively do a dumpbin /imports on every dependant DLL/BPL too, to get a complete recursive list, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For packages you can use the requires section of the PACKAGEINFO resource - see TJclPePackageInfo.

Comment: This works relatively well for compiled BPLs... I was hoping someone would know of a *similar* solution for DLLs and EXEs, but apparently not.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it gets me at least part-way there.

Answer (score 0):

I came across  [this from felix-cobri](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/colibri_utilities/exe_dll_pe_explorer/exe_dll_pe_explorer.html) - its a little rough round the edges but does what I need and that is to list all the DLLS that my exe (or DLL) uses.

http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/colibri_utilities/exe_dll_pe_explorer/exe_dll_pe_explorer.html

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/)' PE Information tool displays the list of bpls and dlls that are implicit loaded into any .exe, .dll or .bpl